# Create relationship in views with custom entity

Tags: entities, views

I have a custom entity (emtr) with a property called unit_tid (that relates to a taxonomy term).

When I create a view of my custom entity I want access to the fields associated with the related taxonomy term.

This question, [Using Drupal7 custom entities in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158183/using-drupal7-custom-entities-in-views), is on the same topic, and started me off on the right path.

So my [hook_views_data_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7) looks like:

```
function my_module_views_data_alter(&$data) {

    $data['emtr']['unit_tid']['relationship'] = array(
        'base' => 'taxonomy_term_data', // the name of the table I'm linking to
        'base field' => 'tid', // the field I'm linking to in taxonomy_term_data
        'relationship field' => 'unit_tid', // the name of the field in the emtr table
        'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
        'label' => t('Unit'),
    );
    //dpm($data);

}
```

However when I edit my view in the field list it says: `Broken/missing handler (Unit_tid)` and if I click on it the popup says:

`The handler for this item is broken or missing and cannot be used. If a module provided the handler and was disabled, re-enabling the module may restore it. Otherwise, you should probably delete this item.`

What am I doing wrong in creating the relationship?

(Other related questions / resources include: [How to add relationship in view for custom entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64875/how-to-add-relationship-in-view-for-custom-entity), [Enable Relationships in Views with Entities?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38069/enable-relationships-in-views-with-entities), [Integrating entities with Views](http://googletorp.com/blog/integrating-entities-views))